# Collinear points

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm doing an exercise from linear algebra exercice's list and I have three points $A(3,1,-2)$, $B(1,5,1)$ and $C(a,b,\frac{5}{2})$.

The answer from list is $a = -3, b = 13$, but I found different values $a = 0, b = 7$.

I found a vector $\vec{v} = B - A$ and $\vec{u} = C - B$, if a vector $v$ is parallel to $u$ then  $\vec{v} = k\vec{u}$. I found $k$ and solved for $a$ and $b$. Am I Correct?

Comment: "The answer from list" is wrong.  For it to be correct $C$ would have to be $C(a,b,7)$.

Answer (score 1):

The line through $A$ and $B$ can be written as
$$
x = (1 - \lambda) A + \lambda B \quad (\lambda \in \mathbb{R})
$$
To hit $C$ we check the third component:
$$
5/2 = (1-\lambda) (-2) + \lambda (1) = -2 + 3 \lambda \iff \\
\lambda = 3/2
$$
Now we use this parameter for the other components
$$
a = (1-3/2) 3 + (3/2) 1 = 3 - 9/2 + 3/2 = 0 \\
b = (1-3/2) 1 + (3/2) 5 = 1 - 3/2 + 15/2 = 7
$$
This seems to be your solution. It should be unique.

[image: view]

([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc7n6.jpg))